# ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC Views in custom Areas dont have the same design as those in the default one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am new to ASP and I am creating ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC application. I just learned about areas and created one named Seller.

I added a controller :

```
[Area("Seller")]
public class SellerController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and a view :

```
<h1>Hello @User.Identity.Name</h1>
<p>Use the menu below or the navigation bar to navigate the site</p>
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Seller" asp-controller="SellerProduct" asp-action="Index">ProductManagement</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now my problem is that the view looks like this :

[image]

Another issue I have is that this line :

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Seller" asp-controller="SellerProduct" asp-action="Index">ProductManagement</a>
```

does not behave like link, but like a text, I mean "ProductManagement" is beeing writen on scree, but if I click it, or hover over it, nothing happens

How can I use the default design that the default pages have, like this one.

[image]

Also if it is relevant I call the SellerControler using this line:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Seller" asp-controller="Seller" asp-action="Index">SellerHome</a>
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Styling:**
You rather need to add `Layout` to your template or add the `_ViewStart.chtml` in the Area folder:

In Template:
`Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";`

Or `_ViewStart.chtml` (Areas > Seller > Views):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To share a common layout for the entire app, move the `_ViewStart.cshtml` from your `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` to the application root folder.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1#shared-layout-for-areas-using-the-_viewstartcshtml-file

> Another issue I have is that this line :
>   `<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Seller" asp-controller="SellerProduct" asp-action="Index">ProductManagement</a>`
>   does not behave like link, but like a text, I mean "ProductManagement" is beeing writen on scree, but if I click it, or hover over it, nothing happens

It is possible that tag helpers do not work as expected, check your `/Views/_ViewImports.cshtml` to add

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```